# Activeadmin: allow guest to view /admin/model.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How do I allow anonymous users to view the generated XML page for a model with Activeadmin?

../admin/categories.xml

I tried adding skipping the authentication filter with no success.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
end
```

Comment: Personally, I've had bad experiences with using `:except` instead of `:only`. I don't know why, just hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update if anyone finds this post. You have to set up Activeadmin with cancan.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/activeadmin/uJCkRkrrfHY

Remember to use the Activeadmin version from github. When this is configured you will have to initiate a dummy guest user - add this to application_controller.rb

```
  def authenticate_admin_user!
    current_user ||= AdminUser.new # guest user
  end
```

Now you will have to configure your cacan permissions

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Category
    end
  end
end
```

cancan screencast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan